# Why redirecting http:// to https:// in go daddy doesn't working?

Tags: https, ssl-certificate

Today I installed the SSL certificate in my GoDaddy hosting account.

 Everything seems to work when I type "https://myDomain.co.il, meaning, my website is secured.
But when I type HTTP://myDomain.co.il, my website is not secured.
As I was looking for an answer to solve this problem, I found an article in GoDaddy that explains how to redirect HTTP to https.
Is says that I need to open a file inside public_html called .htaccess.
Inside the file, I wrote the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?coolexample\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.coolexample.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Unfortunately, it's not working.

Another question, when I'll solve this problem, if I will type [www.myDomain.co.il](http://www.myDomain.co.il) or myDoamin.co.il, will it redirect to https as well?

Comment: Did you actually use `coolexample.com` in the file, or did you substitute your actual domain?

Comment: I changed it to my domain of course.